# Can I trigger an IceFaces action using JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, icefaces

If I have a simple button:

```
   <ice:panelGroup> 
            <ice:commandButton value="foobar" 
            action="#{fileManager.openNoFlashVisiblePopup}" />
   </ice:panelGroup>
```

Is it possible to trigger the action openNoFlashVisiblePopup using just javascript? I know that there IceFaces has a JavaScript bridge but I don't know see a simple way to do just this.

i need to do this because I have a chunk of JavaScript that detects Flash and I need to show a IceFaces popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get the button element by ID and call its `click()` function.

```
document.getElementById('clientId').click();
```

You only need to give the form and button a fixed `id` so that you can use the generated HTML ID as `clientId` in Javascript code.

Comment: True, this would work I but temporarily created the button to open the popup - otherwise I don't need it... I could make the button not visible and trigger it this way but can I do this without a button? In addition I do not have control over the button's id since IceFaces generates it dynamically and uses it's unique id for the purposes of its mechanism.

Comment: You can hide the button using CSS. No, you cannot invoke a JSF action without a JSF UICommand component. As to the ID, did you read the last sentence of my answer? Just give the form and button a fixed ID. Then JSF won't autogenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late in seeing this, but the correct way to handle this (minus perhaps the overly exhuberant error checking) is:

```
        // There's a <div> that looks like: <div class="portletfaces-bridge-body" id="A8660">.
    // We'll find it and pull out the value of the ID to build elementId like: A8660:wtfForm:editeventparent
    var div = null; 
    var divCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i=0; i<divCollection.length; i++) {
        if(divCollection[i].getAttribute("class") == "portletfaces-bridge-body") {
            div = divCollection[i];
            break;
        } 
    }
    if (div == null){
        alert("could not find div portletfaces-bridge-body.");
        return;
    }

    // Pull the id out of divInnerText.
    var id = div.getAttribute("id");
    if (id == null){
        alert("id was null");
    }

    // prepare initializes fields to null so rendered cannot begin until both itemId and parentId are set.
    var prepare = document.getElementById(id + ":wtfForm:editeventprepare");
    if (prepare == null){
        alert("editeventprepare element was not found.");
        return;
    }
    prepare.click();
```